# Time desynchronisation in causally linked example

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Given two frames A and B, where A is the frame standing still on earth and B is the frame of someone approaching earth from 3 light seconds away at half the speed of light. The frames are drawn in spacetime diagrams below:

Frame A:

[image: Frame A]

Frame B:

[image: Frame B]

At event Q, observer B will hold up a red flag, observer A will do the same as soon as they see this (event O). This all makes sense in frame A, but going to frame B we see that observer B sees event O happen before Q. They hence see A put up the red flag before they did so, even though A would only put up their red flag when they see B do it first. How is this possible?

Is this just because I am ignoring the finite speed of light in order to see an event happen? The light cone (45° straight line coming from O) will always be further in time than the event Q, so B should never see event O before they go through event Q. Is what I'm saying correct? I'm just somewhat confused and some clarification about this example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should draw a Minkowski diagram so you have system A and B in the same diagram an everything clears up.

Comment: I have done that before but not sure how that clears it up.

Comment: Your confusion comes from the relativity of simultaneity. Events $O$ and $Q$ are simultaneous for $A$, and they will also be for $B$ iff $B$ is stationary with respect to $A$. This can be seen in the time dependence for the spacial formula of the Lorentz transformation. Note that it's not physical, the signal of the flag leaves $Q$ at least at speed $c$. For example, if it were $c$, $O$ would rather be in coordinates $(0,2)$ for $A$ or (roughly) $(2,4)$ for $B$. It turns out that this time, causality will necessarily be preserved under Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have arrived at that conundrum because you have assumed that A will see the raised flag instantly, which is not true. A will not see the flag raised until the light from that even has travelled over the intervening distance, which will take 3 seconds. If you take that into account you will find that the apparent paradox disappears.